# Calculations in python, how to get input data to give an output

Tags: python

Input Data
X(1,2,3,4,5)
Y(2,4,6,8,10)

Now write a python program that will use this above input to predict what Y will be giving any X. For instance if I give 2, can your program return the correct answer, 4?

Comment: you want a linear regression model solution?

Comment: Hey @Rayman this community helps to solve programming issues, but I may assume that this is a homework or sth.? This is off-topic. On the other hand if this is a honest request, please state the solutions you have already tried and some code otherwise I must assume the latter one. See guidelines on asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Not much of a clear question but if I understood this correct, you could use a  lambda function.

For example, you could do this:

`X = lambda a : a*2`

A lambda function can take any number of arguments, but can only have one expression.

They have a syntax like so:

> lambda *arguments* : *expression*

The expression is executed and the result is returned, in this case `a*2`.

You call them like any other function:

```
>>> X(2)
4
```

[Source + more info](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp)

Comment: The question is about predicting the outcome given some input, not defining a function to do that.

Answer (score -1):

You don't ask something like that

However , here is the solution for that

```
x = int(input("Number X: "));print(f"Y = {x*2}")
```

The program runs:

1. `x` as a variable , `int()` will change something to integers , `input()` will request input from user and `print()` will give an output
2. Input("Something") will print out `Something` and will wait for user to give input
3. `print(f"")` means print with format , `print(f"Y = {x*2}")` will give you an output with
    `x times 2`
4. `;` is for next line , with this you may make your code look shorter

Its not what you want to "`predict`" but for that input and output , you can use the code snippet

 Try run it on your machine

Comment: You aren't explaining why your solution works or what it does -- that's the whole point of an answer. For a beginner, it might be helpful to include an explanation.

Comment: But the question is asking about `predicting` not `defining a function`

Comment: @AAAlex123 That's why i mentioned it..i know what i wrote